# How to set a DC for a limited number of uses spell granted to player?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting

If a player is granted several uses of a spell, is there a rule or other applicable way to set the DC for it?

I am running Dragon of Icespire Peak module and in one of the locations touching the altar grants player a charm of limited uses of Lightning Bolt spell:

> You can cast the lightning bolt spell (3rd-level version) as an action. Once used three times, the charm vanishes from you.

Notably this is missing the DC to use for it.

I ruled DC 10 in the game, because the player (level 3 barbarian) had no spellcasting ability or proficiency, as well as no affinity to the god.

They made a case that Wand of Lightning Bolts casts that spell with a DC of 15, but I disagreed - that it's not what they *actually have*. :) Of note for balance there - the wand requires attunement by a spellcaster.

1. Are there any rules governing such case?
2. Is the DC 10 correct call for a "default" DC?
3. Which stats might make sense to adjust a DC in such case? Primarily spellcasting ability, if any?

Comment: Different adventure, but same rules and same problem, so I’ve closed this as a duplicate (not a bad thing, dupes help point people to questions that have been asked before).

Comment: @ThomasMarkov did not come up in search for me, cheers!

Comment: Yeah, the frequency of the word “charm” used in other contexts made finding this one a nontrivial task for sure.